# Mandar alerta despues de 5 min sin responder un ping?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

He intentado de varias formas hacer un script en bash para esto...

Mi objectivo es hacer un script que haga ping a una ip , y que si deja de responder el ping siga intentando hacer ping durante  5 minutos, sia los 5 minutos sigue sin responder,se mande una alerta o mensaje a otra maquina dentro de la misma red(ip), es decir, se sigue haciendo ping y si volviese la maquina (volver a tener respuesta) dejaria de contar y seguiria en su bucle.

Intente hacer esto de varias formas.. con contador, con sleeps, pero por ejemplo haciendolo asi, no tengo exito:

```
time=0

until [ $time -eq 300 ]
do
        if ! ping -c1 192.168.200.4 &>/dev/null ;then
                ((time++))
                echo $time
        else
                echo "Respuesta"
        fi

done

echo "RIP"
```

en este caso el incremento es muy lento , no uso ni sleep por que cada incremento dura mas de 1 segundo..

la verdad no se como dar solucion a mi concreto problema.
PD: no se que comando usar concretamente para mandar una alerta o mensaje del estilo que se consigue con wall , a otra maquina dentro de la misma red(IP)

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un mensaje podría ser algo tan standard (y complejo) como un mensaje snmp..... pero ya estamos hablando de ligas mayores, con OIDs y demás. Podría ser algo tan sencillo como enviar algo a través de nc/netcat.

Con respecto a la detección que estás tratando de hacer usando ping, tienes que usar -W para indicar que sea de maximo un segundo de espera. La forma en la que estás corriendo el ping desde el if para mi es nueva... más no quiero decir que es incorrecta, sinceramente no lo sé. La forma en la que yo lo escribiría sería:

```
time=0

while [ true ]; do
    ping -c 1 -W 1 una-ip &> /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        time=$(( $time + 1 ))
        # ya hubo un retardo de un segundo asi que no tenemos que hacer mas nada
    else
        # hubo respuesta, reseteamos... y esperamos un segundo
        time=0
        sleep 1
    fi

    if [ $time -eq 300 ]; then
        # solo en los 300.... si nos pasamos, pues ya avisamos
        echo "el equipo no responde" | nc otro-equipo 9999 # enviamos el mensaje
    fi

done
```

De pronto se me está escapando algo pero eso debería ser suficiente.

Comment: una cosa, para mandar use ```echo "hola" | nc -w1 otro-equipo 9999``` y desde el otro pc previamente lanze ```nc -lk -p 9999``` pero cuando se manda el mensaje , se corta la conexion por la parte del receptor, como puedo hacer para que escucche continuamente? , o mandar un mensaje y que no se quede ahi esperando, por que si no añado -w1 tengo que hacer ctrl+c para salir...

Comment: Podrías encerrar la llamada a `nc -l` dentro de un while.... o escribir tu propio daemon _a pie_ para que escuche las conexiones, lea lo que le quiera decir el cliente y regrese a escuchar conexiones.... o hacerlo multi hilos para que escuche conexiones de varios clientes al mismo tiempo.... o tambien..... y así sucesivamente. El cielo es el límite.

Comment: entonces lo que hago es hacer un while para que si cierro la conexcion por la parte del emisor , vuelva a escuchar y asi en bucle , abriendo y cerrandose (a causa del emisor) correcto?

Comment: Pues es algo que intentaría... sin embargo veo que estás usando `-k` que _teoricamente hablando_ debe hacer que nc se quede escuchando otras conexiones, cierto? raro. Pero bueno.... ya tienes el concepto.

Comment: una cosa, por ejemplo , en tu codigo ```echo "el equipo no responde" | nc otro-equipo 9999 # enviamos el mensaje``` si hago esto en el script , se queda ahi abierta la conexion , no manda y ya esta , se queda ahi... , como solvento esto? , probe con ```killall nc``` o usando ```echo "el equipo no responde" | nc -w1 -4u otro-equipo 9999``` pero este ultimo comando , no recibe el receptor el mensaje.. cuando deberia hacerlo , lo de -u es porque quiero que sea mediante UDP

Comment: usar udp tiene sentido.... y _supongo_ que se queda pegado porque el "listener" no está escuchando... dejame probar por aqui

Comment: perdona antes me equivoque en la escucha uso ```nc -lk - u-p 9999 ``` para que acepte UDP

Comment: aqui hice una prueba y al usar -u, el "listener" se queda pegado luego de que el cliente le envía el mensaje. Bien usas TCP si quieres que el listener muera o indagas al respecto ya que sale del ámbito de la pregunta original.

Comment: de acuerdo gracias , creare otro post, dado que ya andube mirando y nada